# How to make one column upper case in pandas and return all other columns?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, data-manipulation

Error at the moment, now I want to return all the columns and data but just make one column need to be upper.

```
hellodf= hellodf.loc[hellodf['ContactName'].str.upper()]
```

Answer (score 2):

Use [`Series.str.isupper`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.isupper.html) for filter:

```
hellodf= hellodf.loc[hellodf['ContactName'].str.isupper()]
```

If need convert one column to uppercase:

```
hellodf['ContactName'] = hellodf['ContactName'].str.upper()
```

Comment: the OP asked "make one column need to be upper", whereas your answer only uses the isupper() function, which only "checks" if the string is upper or not.

Comment: @AnandSowmithiran - OK, added to answer.

Answer (score 0):

Use the Series.str.upper() function to make the strings in a certain column to uppercase. Below is the actual code that works,

```
other=hellodf['ContactName'].str.upper()

#convert the series to a DF
other=pd.DataFrame(other) 

newdf=hellodf.join(other,rsuffix='_upper')

#to drop the initial coulmn, and retain only the uppercased column
newdf=newdf.drop(['ContactNname'], axis=1)
```